# Delta function multiplied by an exponential function

Tags: distribution-theory

I do not know if this is an ill-posed question but ...
is $\delta(t)e^{-\gamma t}$ equal to $\delta(t)$?

Thanks,
biologist

Comment: Not every distribution is a function, which is why some mathematicians get really touchy when they hear "delta function". (Myself included. :) ) One possible layman view for distributions is "distributions are functions which only live under integrals", and under the integral these two "functions" are the same, as tabstops answer shows.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is supposed to live under an integral as it is a fundamental solution (Green's function). However, in the definition of the fundamental solution there is no integral (the way I see it), e.g. $LF(x) = \delta(x)$. How can the above equation hold then, if there is no integral? Do differential operators act differently on distributions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what I think you mean, then:
$$\int_{\Bbb R} f(t)\delta(t)\,dt = f(0)$$
and
$$\int_{\Bbb R} f(t)\delta(t)e^{-\gamma t}\,dt=f(0)e^{-\gamma\cdot0}=f(0).$$
which works because your "extra" function evaluates to $1$ at the support of $\delta$. So they form identical kernels to integrate against, and that seems like probably what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a little bit ill-posed. $e^{-\gamma t}$ does not play well with tempered distributions. The delta distribution is a tempered distribution, meaning that it is in the dual space to the Schwartz functions (functions that are smooth and decay exponentially). Examples of such functions are the functions of the form $\exp(-t^{2n})$ where $n$ is a natural number. So you can't be sure that it makes sense to integrate the delta distribution against $\exp(-\gamma t)$. However if you *could*, then you would be correct.

Comment: This was in the context of proving that $F(t) = \theta(t)\exp(-\gamma t)$, where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside distribution, is a fundamental solution for the linear partial differential operator $L = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \gamma$. Are you saying that this distribution equality does not hold for certain functions?

Comment: I mean for certain test functions $\varphi(t)$ that can be used in the corresponding  inhomogeneous PDE? Thank you.

Comment: Oh in this case, that is fine because you are lopping off the "exponentially growing" part of the exponential. If you were not modulating with a Heaviside, you would run into some problems.

Comment: @cameronwilliams Inasmuch as the Dirac Delta has support on $\{0\}$, the functional.$\langle f,\delta\rangle =f(0)$ makes sense for $f(x)=e^{ax}$.