# Impulse function and exponential, integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble understanding this integral:

$$ y =\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t+2)e^{-t}dt = e^2$$

I'm having trouble visualizing what this function looks like. Is $\delta(t+2)$ an infinite line along the y-axis, shifted to left by $2$? And why doesn't this integral $ = e^{-2}$?

Comment: Because $\int \delta(x-a) f(x)\ dx = f(a)$. In your case $a = -2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The object "$\delta(x)$" is not a function, but rather a [Generalized Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) or [Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870), I provided primers on the Dirac Delta.

We facilitate visualizing the Dirac Delta through a simple regularization.   To proceed, let $\delta_n(x)$ be the family of functions defined by

$$
\delta_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
n/2,&-\frac{1}{n}\le x\le \frac{1}{n}\\\\
0,&\text{otherwise} \tag1
\end{cases}$$

Note that $\delta_n(x)$, as given by $(1)$, is a "pulse" function that is centered at the origin and has height $n/2$ and width $2/n$.  Hence, the area under $\delta_n(x)$ is identically equal to $1$ for all $n$.  Moreover, we see that $\delta_n(x)$ has the properties that

$$\lim_{n\to  \infty}\delta_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&,x\ne 0\\\\\infty&,x=0\end{cases}$$

and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta_n(x-a)\,dx=f(a)} \tag 2$$

for all suitable test functions $f$.  The property in $(2)$ is called the "sifting" property of the Dirac Delta.

Hence, we can formally write the regularization as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\delta(x)\sim \lim_{n\to \infty}\delta_n(x)} \tag 3$$

where $(3)$ is interpreted to imply $(2)$.

---

> Applying $(2)$ to the case for which $a=-2$ and $f(x)=e^{-t}$, we find that
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t}\delta(t+2)\,dt&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t}\delta_n(t+2)\,dt\\\\
> &=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-2-1/n}^{-2+1/n} e^{-t}\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\,dt\\\\
> &=e^{-(-2)}\\\\
> &=e^2
> \end{align}$$
>
> And we are done!

Comment: But see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663390).

Comment: @joriki Inasmuch as the Dirac Delta has support on $\{0\}$, all is well with the world in defining $\langle f,\delta\rangle$ for $f(t)=e^{at}$.